# Error Installing Lubuntu to Thumb Drive

Tags: lubuntu, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 22.04 to a 16GB thumb drive from the Lubuntu ISO installer running in VirtualBox.  I think that maybe my selected options are incorrect because it keeps giving me this error:

[image]

Here is the summary of the settings that I'm using.  What's wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Did you hashcheck the downloaded ISO? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Did you verify the ISO?  as *squashfs* errors are read errors on the media itself being detected & thus the data should not be trusted. Also if this is a VM, Oracle have stated errors will occur (causing *squashfs*) in their software due to what they call user-errors; ie. insufficient RAM being allocated to the VM by the operator & `virtualbox` struggling. Oracle documented this as user-procedure error as `virtualbox` works properly if giving sufficient resources for the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved and was able to install Lubuntu 22.04 to my 16GB thumb drive using this configuration:

- GPT partition table
- 200MB FAT32 partition with `boot` flag mounted at /boot/efi
- 8MB unformatted partition with `bios-grub` flag
- 8192MB (8GB) ext4 partition with `root` flag mounted at /
- Remaining space (7.21GB) ext4 partition (no flags) mounted at /home

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-) By the way, did you notice that you can install Ubuntu Server directly by extracting and cloning from a compressed image file, and into that system later on install `lubuntu-desktop`? There are amd64 compressed image files (just like there are arm files for that kind of installation). See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).

Comment: While I normally suggest 300 to 500MB for the ESP on large drives, you only need 100MB for a small flash drive. A bios_grub partition only is 1MB unformatted. You only need both if installing both UEFI & BIOS versions of grub. And since smaller drive, often better to have just / (root) so unused space is shared, rather than having unused space in one partition and later needing it in the other.